# How to find the min and max values produced by stat_summary_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggplot` to display a series of basemaps with a `stat_summary_hex` layer to show net change in population.  To rescale my values for `scale_fill_gradientn` I need to know the `min` and `max` `..value..` produced by `stat_summary_hex`.

Here's a simplified example:

```
Hex_Summary <- stat_summary_hex(aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, z = Churn),
   bins=100, colour = NA, geom = "hex", fun = function(x) sum(x))
```

I've tried the following to get the min and max values produced by the function `fun`:

```
PlotEnv <- ggplot() + HexSummary
PlotData <-ggplot_build(PlotEnv)  

BinnedValues <- PlotData[["data"]][[1]]$value
BinMin <- min(BinnedValues) 
BinMax <- max(BinnedValues)
```

However, the data from `ggplot_build` that I've been able to access (`PlotData[["data"]][[1]]$value`) does not match the values in the actual plot.

Per Henrik's comment: when I added a geom_text to the plot,

```
hexlab <- stat_summary_hex(geom="text",
  aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, z = Churn, label=..value..), size = 1, color="black",
  fun = function(x) (sum(x)))
```

I can see the maximum value for a binned hexagon is 79; however, when I do

```
PlotData[["data"]][[1]]$value
```

which I assumed was the data behind the plot, I see the max value is only 29.  Also, the number of rows in the `PlotData[["data"]][[1]]` does not equal the number of hexagons plotted. It looks like using ggplot_build is not a legitimate way to see the results of the binned function.

In general, is there a **better** way to access a data frame with all of the co-ordinates and values from the `stat_summary_hex` function.  Or, is there a proper way to simply determine the minimum and maximum values produce by the function in the  `stat_summary_hex` statement?

EDIT: After going back to document what exactly was different, I found the cause: my actual function was more complicated than the first example given:

```
stat_summary_hex(aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, z = Churn),
  bins=100, colour = NA, geom = "hex", drop = TRUE,
  fun = function(x) if(abs(sum(x)) > 5) {sum(x)} else {NA})
```

Why this affects the sums for other hex locations doesn't reason.  E.g. in a given cell where the sum should have been 79, the max value from `ggplot_build` was 29, but when changed the function and set `drop = F`, I see the expected value of 79.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by "the data from ggplot_build [...] does not match the values in the actual plot".

Comment: Thanks for the nudge Henrik - I went to go document the difference and found that an earlier version of the solution worked fine.  It was all about the drop NA.